# cut object from path not working in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am very new to using `inkscape`. I have been learning from a huge amount of tutorials available over the net.
However, one thing that never works for me is "cut out from objects"

I've attached a [screencast](http://youtu.be/16xYDXHdATs) to actually explain what I mean. 
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: you first need to select the circle, expand appearance and then use the rubber

Comment: Please provide details about your question. There is nothing here but a link to the screencast, which not everyone will be able to view. Please explain what the problem is and what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the object locked? or should I say do you have a setting set up to lock objects when placing them?
Or you may somehow you may have another layer on top of that layer. or maybe even a software problem because it should be just simply drop the object on canvas select the eraser tool and erase simple as that. I saw your video. Then I opened inkscape did exactly what you did several times and i was able to erase everytime.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have them...I don't know if inkscape "lock" them by default....but I have not found any such option.

Answer (score 1):

I've found, if you are combining with other paths, that you may need to reverse the path before you combine it and then clip